# R: Run for loop in parallel

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to read in two csv files (dataset1 and dataset2) one of them has about 400 million lines. Both the files have the same number of columns i.e. 7.

In the code below, I am reading both files in chunks of fixed size, rbind them, apply a function and then write out the returned output to a file in append mode.

The following is my code:

```
# set x to 0 - number of lines to skip in dataset1
# set y to 7924 - number of lines to read in dataset1
# dataset1 has 60498*7924
x = 0
y = 7924

# set a to 0 - number of lines to skip in dataset2
# set b to 734 - number of lines to read in dataset2
# dataset2 has 60498*734 lines
a = 0
b = 734

# run the loop from 1 to 60498
# each time skip lines already read in
# each time read fixed number of rows
for(i in 1:60498)
{
  # read both datasets and combine in one
  dat <- read.csv('dataset1.csv', skip = x, nrows = y, header = F)
  dat2 <- read.csv('dataset2.csv', skip = a, nrows = b, header = F)
  dat3 <- rbind(dat, dat2)

  # apply function to this dataset and return the output
  # the function is too long and not in the scope so I will skip it
  # it returns a dataframe of 1 row
  res <- limma.test(dat3)

  # write out the output in append mode
  # so at the end of the loop, out.txt should have 60498 lines
  write.table(res, file = 'out.txt', append = TRUE, quote = F, col.names = F)

  # set x and y so that it skips the lines that are already read in 
  x = x + 7924
  a = a + 734
}
```

The function itself is pretty fast, there is no bottleneck there. However, running a `for loop` for 60498 times, it is going to take really long. I have a computer with 8 cores. How can I modify my code to run the for loop in parallel to minimize the time?

Thanks!

Comment: you can try `data.table::fread()`, it much quicker than `read.csv()`

Comment: Why `read.csv` inside loop? Does omitted function modify *dat*, *dat2*, *dat3* with each loop iteration?

Comment: check our the `parallel` or `snow` packages if you really want to parallelize. `parLapply` will do what you're after, though as Hubert said, just working with fread, or using a different format like feather or RDS is probably good enough for what you're after.

Comment: You can't write to a file in parallel. It would be easy and much faster to avoid writing to file in each iteration.

Comment: @Roland: Okay I can choose not to write to a file and write it later as a whole

Comment: read.csv doesn't take too long actually thats why I did not have the data.table fread function.